# How to add a number at end of each row of un-equal length columns of data frame in r

Tags: r

New to R and apologies if I am asking wrong :

How to add a number at each end of the row of unequal length of columns ?

Sample code:

```
x = 1:12
y = 1:10
z=1:8

attributes(df) = list(names = names(df),row.names=1:max(length(x), length(y),length(z)), class='data.frame')
df
#    x    y    z
#1   1    1    1
#2   2    2    2
#3   3    3    3
#4   4    4    4
#5   5    5    5
#6   6    6    6
#7   7    7    7
#8   8    8    8
#9   9    9 <NA>
#10 10   10 <NA>
#11 11 <NA> <NA>
#12 12 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks and sample code updated

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Before the call to `attributes` what you have is a `list`, not a `data.frame`, and want to make its members all of the same length?

Comment: sorry i didnt get u ...@Rui Barradas

Comment: need to add number "3" for every end of the row to the total data frame but at the 9th row end there is NA so it has to be replace with 3, similar to 10th row also, but for 11th and 12th row only y columns has to replace with 3 not z column @markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to transform a list of vectors of unequal length into a `data.frame`, filling the vectors with `NA`'s your code is not right, this one is better.

```
x <- 1:12 
y <- 1:10 
z <- 1:8 
df <- list(x = x, y = y, z = z) 

n <- max(sapply(df, length))

df <- lapply(df, function(x){
  c(x, rep(NA, n - length(x)))
})
df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, df)
```

The following code will replace the first `NA` in each row with the value `3`.
It loops through the rows using `apply` and changes the rows whith at least one `NA` value.

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x){
  if(anyNA(x)){
    i <- min(which(is.na(x)))
    x[i] <- 3
  }
  x
}))

df
#    x  y  z
#1   1  1  1
#2   2  2  2
#3   3  3  3
#4   4  4  4
#5   5  5  5
#6   6  6  6
#7   7  7  7
#8   8  8  8
#9   9  9  3
#10 10 10  3
#11 11  3 NA
#12 12  3 NA
```

Comment: @saisaran The error comes from your call to `attributes`, to see it run `str(df)`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @saisaran Done.

Comment: thats great and worked for me now...superb . @Rui Barradas